# How to find restriction enzyme frequency in whole genome and count the distance between them?

Tags: python, r, linux, fasta

I am having possibly a simple question which is proving difficult.

My objective is to take the reference FASTA file and flat file database with 1500 restriction enzymes with its cutting sites (mostly pattern I would say).

1. I first want to see that how many times each enzyme cut the FASTA file and;
2. second to check the number and size of fragment that each enzyme would give me, this output pregerably would be a CSV file may be.

**Background** I tried to do pattern search using R, but its just collapsing my system. I am looking for bash command may be.

Comment: This looks like the RAM load of the reg-ex in R. Bash isn't the best for reg-ex style commands IMO, Python can do this, I would assume awk too, and dare I say Perl is really good.

Answer (score 2):

Biopython has a module dedicated to working with [restriction enzymes](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/cookbook/Restriction.html). Without any code examples we cannot help you much further.

Answer (score 2):

The `diffHic` package might have solved this issue in R.

```
# Load the genomic data
genome <- biostrings::readDNAStringSet("your_file.fa")

# Run the in silico restriction digest 
cuts <- cutGenome(genome, "CCGCGG", overhang=2L) # SacII
```

the `cuts` GRanges object contains the boundaries of each restriction fragment for given genome.